# How to split string from String array [] by strings (word by by word instead of characters) with delimitter?

Tags: java, string

```
void displayResult() {
    String str = "tamilnadu||chennai-karanataka||bengaluru";
    String[] res = str.split("\\-");
    System.out.println(res.length);//res length is 2 

    //res contains two strings splited by -
    String[] result = res.toString().split("\\||");
    //again splitting by || but getting as characters, i need to get word by      word
    // how to achieve this
    System.out.println(result.length);//result length is 28
}
// i was supposed to get tamilnadu and chennai from first string[] res
```

String[] res holds two strings split by - i am trying to split res in the same way to get strings split by || pipe symbol but i am getting as characters 
how to get as like before

Comment: Why would you escape just one of the bar characters?  Did you mean to write `"\\|\\|"`?

Comment: Hi Dawood i need to get states as key and capitals as value in map so
i am splitting given string to get word by word so that i can try to add in map

Comment: i did modified let me check dawood , thanks for your time 
String[] result = res.toString().split("\\|\\|");

Comment: @user2926683 you need to escape both characters of `||`, but besides that, look what calling `toString()` on an array produces; it’s not useful for further processing. If you want to process the array elements, use a loop.

Comment: hi holger actually i though \\ this will escape all characters after this whatever we are adding as i am new i just now got to know it will escape only one pipe sympol
instead of two

Answer (score 2):

Don't use split method two times.you can complete your task with one split method. like this,

```
 void displayResult() {

   String str = "tamilnadu||chennai-karanataka||bengaluru";

   String[] res = str.split("\\|\\||-");

   for(String city : res){

     System.out.println(city);

   }

 }
```

your output will be:-

> tamilnadu
>
> chennai
>
> karanataka
>
> bengaluru

Comment: yeah and why i did split is i need to add it states into keys and city into values
in map so as a beginner i am confused with regex your pgm too would work fin
i can add it by looping array into map. thanks for adding new logic bro

Comment: This seems to be identical to lucumt's answer. Can you please clarify what value you've added by repeating it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two `\` to escape `|`,so the regex is `\\|\\||-` ,we can get the words with only one `split`

```
    String str = "tamilnadu||chennai-karanataka||bengaluru";
    String[] strs = str.split("\\|\\||-");
    for(String s:strs){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Output is

```
tamilnadu
chennai
karanataka
bengaluru
```

Comment: this one exactly what i am expecting thanks for assisting me

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `res.toString`. It will return something like this:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@2c7b84de
```

Instead, you can split on the elements in res with regex `\|\|`:

```
String[] result = res[0].split("\\|\\|");
System.out.println(result.length); // 2
```

Comment: this one also working fine and res[0] is displaying for ony one string
if i want to get for i need to use for loop with re.length for each string am i right John...?

Comment: @user2926683 yeah. you need a `for` loop then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must be trying your hands with learning Regex. You could use `|` operator to specify `OR` condition. So if you use following you should get desired array :

> String[] res =  str.split("\-|\|\|");

i.e. your method will be :

```
void displayResult(){
    String str = "tamilnadu||chennai-karanataka||bengaluru";
    String[] res =  str.split("\\-|\\|\\|"); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(res)); // don't forget to import Arrays
}
```

Comment: Vinay bro thanks for your time, one more thing how can i add using map
states as keys and capitals as value  .. please give me clue only instead of code
let me try bro...do i need to split odd and even position of array index , is it possible?

Comment: what is the pattern of finding state and capital in the string? Is it state || capital & state-capital ?

Comment: you could simply loop through array on a gap of 2 and put into the map.

Comment: Sema bro , thanks much i could able to put keys and values with odd in keys and
even index on values it is working.....

Answer (score 0):

```
you split the **str** into substrings and stored in **res** array,again 
your 
trying to split the substrings, you should specify that which substring going 
to split. 
void displayResult() {
String str = "tamilnadu||chennai-karanataka||bengaluru";
String[] res = str.split("\\-");
System.out.println(res.length);
**String[] result = res[0].toString().split("\\|");**
for (String string : result) {
System.out.println(string);
}
System.out.println(result.length);
}
output:
2 
tmailnadu
chennai
3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer would be more useful if you explained the changes you have made in the code and how they resolve the problem.

Comment: Hanumanth i did answered what i did with my code to all who ever answered 
check my comments in each answer you probably get an idea what i have tried and how i got solutions from seniors...